# Change Trash name (or date format)

Tags: raspbian

I chose British English for my RPi because I want the date format to be like DD/MM/YYYY. But, as a consequence, the trash has been renamed "wastebasket".

How can I can change that name to have Trash (I tried with GUI, but I got the error : Operation not supported by backend), or at least the date format in the US English.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Language specifications includes date format AND translations.

If you want to change a specific text in the translation, there is a tricky method here: https://askubuntu.com/a/253396/650621 (for ubuntu unity, but the solution should be similar)

But if your only problem with the US locale is date format, you should install Raspbian in en_US and then there is an option to change locale for time and date only and maybe also numbers, not sure. It should be in `Preferences->Language Support->Regional Formats`. (Or environnement variable LC_TIME if you prefer to change it in command line)

*Raspbian uses LXDE as desktop manager, you will have more luck if you search on the Internet how to do something LXDE, it's how I found the answers above.*